# Trailing fade to complete black with PIXI.js and WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

I have application made using PIXI.js and it uses a WebGLRenderer.

I'm preserving the drawing buffer and not clearing before render:

```
{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true, clearBeforeRender: false }
```

This allows me to create trails as objects move around.
I want the trails to fade out over time, so I apply a transparent black rectangle on top over every rendering. This works, but the fade out eventually rounds off to gray. I want a complete fade to black.

I've tried using a `ColorMatrixFilter` filter with a lowered brightness on my root container, hoping it would cause a fade effect. It didn't cause any fade effect, instead just causing everything to be slightly darker. If that had worked, then a custom filter could help to do the job.

How can I get a slow gradual fade to complete black for the trails of my rendered objects?

**EDIT:** Here are a few examples of what I've tried:

```
// `this` being my app object.
this.fadeGraphics           = new PIXI.Graphics()
this.root.addChild(this.fadeGraphics)

// Blend Mode
this.fadeGraphics.blendMode = PIXI.BLEND_MODES.MULTIPLY
this.fadeGraphics.beginFill(0xf0f0f0)
this.fadeGraphics.drawRect(0, 0, this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight)
this.fadeGraphics.endFill()

// Transparent black rectangle.
this.fadeGraphics.beginFill(0x000000, .05)
this.fadeGraphics.drawRect(0, 0, this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight)
this.fadeGraphics.endFill()
```

Both these methods leave me with a gray trail, the trail goes away if my values are strong enough. Though, I want a very long-term trail so I have to use small values, and possibly also apply them every nth frame.

I think a SUBTRACT blend mode might be able to do what I need.
Unfortunately it doesn't seem available in Pixi.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out that fading to white works wonderfully.

Thus, one solution is to fade to white, then invert color, and rotate hue 180 degrees.

You can do this with a CSS filter on your canvas, though it doesn't work in all browsers, has a performance hit, and all your color intensities get inverted.